# OR filter on MultipleChoices with django-filter

Tags: django, django-filter

I have a form field with choices like [1, 2, 3, 4+], that 4+ means `greater than equal` and multiple choices can be selected. I want to do the filter using `django-filter`.

I could do the filter for [1, 2, 3], but I don't know how to `or` it with `gte=4`.

both the following work for filtering [1,2,3]:

```
class NumberInFilter(django_filters.BaseInFilter, django_filters.NumberFilter):
    pass

class PlanFilter(FilterSet):
    obj = django_filters.NumberInFilter(name='object', lookup_expr='in')
    class Meta:
        model = Plan 
        fields= ['object',]
```

or

```
choices= ( 
         (1,1),
         (2,2),
         (3,3),
         )

class PlanFilter(FilterSet):
    obj = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(name='object', choices=choices) 
    ...
```

So how can I filter the multiple choices with a `gte=4` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either option should only require a minimal change to the filter logic.

#### Custom `.filter()` method for `NumberInFilter`

```py
class NumberInFilter(django_filters.BaseInFilter, django_filters.NumberFilter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        # CSV-based filters receive a list of values
        if 4 not in value:
            return super(NumberInFilter, self).filter(qs, value)

        value.remove(4)

        # a little bit more verbose, but doesn't require hardcoding the name.
        # eg, `qs.filter(Q(object__in=value) | Q(object__gte=4))`
        q1 = Q(**{'%s__%s' % (self.name, 'in'): value})
        q2 = Q(**{'%s__%s' % (self.name, 'gte'): 4})
        return qs.filter(q1 | q2)
```

#### Overriding `.get_filter_predicate()` in `MultipleChoiceFilter`

```py
ObjectMultipleChoiceFilter(django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter):
    def get_filter_predicate(self, value):
        if value == '4':
            return {'%s__gte' % self.name: 4}
        return super(ObjectMultipleChoiceFilter, self).get_filter_predicate(value)
```

Comment: Thanks, these both work with slight changes: `super()` needs to have arguments, `super(NumberInFilter,value)`. and `if value==4` has to be `if value==u'4'`.

Comment: I have a question though, if I add `get_queryset()` method to my view, I get an error on `theNumberInFilter` on the line `return super(NumberInFilter,value).filter(qs, value)`. Error: `super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Good point about the value. you could get around this by using `TypedMultipleChoiceFilter` instead. As to the `super()` calls, python 3 accepts a no-argument version. In python 2 you have to pass the class and self values. In your case, you passed `value`, but need to pass `self`. eg, `super(NumberInFilter, self)`